# Write a program that reads numbers entered and then returns the total, help pls

Tags: python, numbers

Can someone help me pls? i need to write a program that reads numbers entered and then return the total without using 'for' or 'while' and i have no idea how to do it:(

```
n = 0
count = 0 # `enter code here`
user = input('Enter Numbers:\n> ')
while user != 'done':
    try:
        n = n + float(user)
    except:
        print('Enter Numbers or "done"')
    user = input('> ')
    count = count + 1
    if user == 'done':
        print('Total:',n)

# this works for me but i need to do it without using loops like 'for' or 'while' :(
```

Comment: how can you do it without using a loop or similar construct? will you know how many numbers to expect at least?

Comment: I think maybe you mean to let user enter a single string, with numbers separated by space or similar? in that case, it's possible to do it without a loop.

Comment: something like: `total = sum(map(int, input('Enter Numbers separated by space:\n> ').split())); print(total)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
numbers = []
def loop():
    n = input('Enter Numbers or done:\n>')
    if n == 'done':
        print('Total:', sum(numbers))
    else:
        numbers.append(int(n))
        loop()
loop()
```